# How to save output to folder using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, xmlserializer

I have a test that I am using to create sample xml data. Currently the output is being saved to my desktop. What I want to do is to save the file to a folder in the test project i.e. `/outputs`. Is there a way I can do this using reflection or some other means?

```
[TestMethod]
        public void ProduceSampleIndicativeData()
        {
            var process_serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProcessIndicativeDataType));
            var sync_serailizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (SyncIndicativeDataType));

            XmlWriter process_writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\ProcessIndicativeData.xml", new UTF8Encoding());
            XmlWriter synch_writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\SyncIndicativeData.xml",new UTF8Encoding());

            var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add("", "http://www.hr-xml.org/3");
            namespaces.Add("oa", "http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9");
            namespaces.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

            process_serializer.Serialize(process_writer, processIndicativeData, namespaces);
            sync_serailizer.Serialize(synch_writer,syncIndicativeData,namespaces);

        }
```

I've tried

```
string ProcessIndicativeDataLocation = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"OutputFiles\ProcessIndicativeData.xml");
```

but this points to `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\...`

Comment: When you say project folder, do you mean the directory the project is stored in, or the one it runs in? I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: I'm referring to the folder that the project is running in @TonyHopkinson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx

Comment: Thats give me the same result as that i have above but I understood what was being required of me so this does actually meet the requirements.

Comment: the other one would be getting the path of the executing assembly.